# Unable to fetch bccRecipients, ccRecipients and toRecipients via gmail event object

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I am creating a Gmail add-on, basically I want to get **bcc, cc and to** emails once the user clicks on an email.

I have defended **onTriggerFunction** in the manifest for that, also added **metadata** scope. But **bccRecipients**, **ccRecipients** and **toRecipients** attributes are **null** in gmail event object.

Manifest

```
"gmail": {
  "contextualTriggers": [{
    "unconditional": {
    },
    "onTriggerFunction": "onGmailMessage"
  }]
}
```

Scope

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata
```

Comment: Are you able to retrieve other Gmail event objects? Show your code.

Comment: function look like: 
`function onGmailMessage(e) { Logger.log(e.gmail); }`

output: 
`{messageId=msg-f:1670823024080259424, threadId=thread-f:1670823024080259424, accessToken=AN68bGZPxBW2UNSRNU38c6nj4qPPEqraqzIPdS
}`

Answer (score 1):

The [Gmail event object](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/event-objects#gmail_event_object) contains the following information:

- gmail.accessToken string
- gmail.bccRecipients[] list of strings
- gmail.ccRecipients[]  list of strings
- gmail.messageId   string
- gmail.threadId    string
- gmail.toRecipients[]      list of strings

### `bccRecipients`, `ccRecipients` and `toRecipients` are arrays.

To access the elements contained in those arrays you need to loop through them.

E.g. `e.gmail.bccRecipients.forEach(function(recipient){Logger.log(recipient)});`

Comment: problem was not getting bccRecipients, so can't forEach I am getting an exception: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

Comment: Are you sure that the email contains bccRecipients?

Comment: yes, you can see my log, none of the recipient attribute is available

Comment: Can you open the message with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get) and have a look at its structure?